# Is there a name for a set where any two elements are separated by a given distance?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I am curious if there is a name for such a set.
Let $(M,d)$ be a metric space and $S$ a subset of $M$ for which there is some positive number $\delta$ such that for any two distinct elements in $S$, $x$ and $y$, $d(x,y) > \delta$ ?

Just curious,
Matt

Comment: I would call it the inner diameter.  If you imagine the end of a tube, it has an inner diameter $diam(A) = \sup \{d(x,y) : x, y \in A\}.$  And the $\text{inner diam of } A = \inf \{ d(x,y) : \dots \}$.  In this way, you'd say $S$ is of *inner diameter* $d$ and take that to mean for any $d \geq \delta \gt 0$ all $d(x,y)$ are $\gt \delta$ in $S$.

Comment: Or you could call it uniformly discrete (with constant $δ$).

Comment: Thank you for your input!  I like both terms (esp "inner diameter"), I didn't recognize this property as being a commonly named one, but I thought I would just ask to make sure .